# Как создать квадратный символ в консоли Python?

Tags: python, консоль

Моя задача - сделать символ с одинаковой длиной и шириной и вывести его в консоль. Как это сделать?

Comment: программно вряд ли получится, можно выбрать шрифт или использовать юникод символы если подойдут

Comment: @DaniilLoban как написать в консоли допустим другим шрифтом или юникод символами?

Comment: ответил, другие сиволы юникода можно поискать в интернете, помимо это их можно вводить так `u'\u2713' ` где 2713 код символа

Comment: @TheNick-Ник выбрать нужный шрифт в настройках консоли.

Comment: Вот вам два квадратика на выбор, копируйте: ■   □

Answer (score 5):

А вот и решение в духе 80x -:)

```
print('-----')
print('|   |')
print('|   |')
print('-----')
```

Comment: впринципе, умно, и это сработало в отличии от ответа выше.

Comment: @TheNick-Ник , я не в обиде, но может все же лучше разобраться почему не сработало?

Comment: @DaniilLoban ну тогда ответь, почему не сработало и как решить.

Comment: TheNick - Ник, тогда, если лучше ничего не найдётся, не забудьте принять ответ потом:-))

Answer (score 4):

По сути берется любой подходящий квадратик, копируется в память, далее

в коде программы можно написать:

```
print('⬜️') # выведет нужный символ
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот я запустил скрипт и получил квадратик:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что касается `Windows` то там реально все сложно:) Прежде всего я поставил фонт `Hack` который у меня на `Linux` (просто чтобы было одинаково). Далее через реестр прописал шрифт

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Microsoft \ Windows NT \ CurrentVersion \ Console \ TrueTypeFont`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто добавил строковый парамет с ключем `000` и значением `Hack`

после чего можно переходить в настройки консоли и выбрать там шрифт

далее уже тест:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Если нужно просмотреть какие символы и коды есть в шрифте можно воспользоваться онлайн сайтом https://fontdrop.info (иногда очень спасает)*

Comment: в Windows отображается как квадратик с вопросом внутри, и это не квадрат, а прямоугольник. если скопировать и вставить сюда, то галочка (✓)

Comment: ну и не мешало бы добавить в тэги вопроса `windows`, сейчас гляну там, отпишусь в ответе, скорее всего нужно в системе шрифт поставить (но это не точно)

Comment: TheNick - Ник слушай чувак тебе подсказали как вывести Юникод в консоль конкретно кубик а как он у тебя там отображается и на каком калькуляторе ты запускаешь Пайтон это уже твои проблемы

Comment: "ну тогда ответь, почему не сработало и как решить." Тебе что кто то чем то здесь обязан?

Comment: Сергей (с высоты своих девяноста лет, покряхтывая): "Всё бы вам, молодёжь, ругаться, да за модными штуками гнаться. Виндовзы какие-то, хаки, да Линухи. Вот в восьмидесятые на PDP11 символами все рисовали, включая "шутеры" (как вы их теперь называете новомодно), все были довольны, и не было таких проблем. И не ругались." :-))